Encountered Bug After Using PandasAI (Agent) Inside My App and Standalone with PyInstaller
I'm implementing an app using PyQt5. To analyze my data, I integrated PandasAI. While running the program directly, everything works fine. However, after standalone packaging with PyInstaller and running it, when I ask something from my agent, I encounter the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandasai/pipelines/chat/generate_chat_pipeline.py", line 283, in run
    output = (self.code_generation_pipeline | self.code_execution_pipeline).run(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandasai/pipelines/pipeline.py", line 137, in run
    raise e
  File "pandasai/pipelines/pipeline.py", line 101, in run
    step_output = logic.execute(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandasai/pipelines/chat/code_execution.py", line 126, in execute
    code_to_run = self._retry_run_code(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandasai/pipelines/chat/code_execution.py", line 346, in _retry_run_code
    return self.on_retry(code, e)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandasai/pipelines/chat/generate_chat_pipeline.py", line 128, in on_code_retry
    return self.code_exec_error_pipeline.run(correction_input)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandasai/pipelines/chat/error_correction_pipeline/error_correction_pipeline.py", line 47, in run
    return self.pipeline.run(input)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandasai/pipelines/pipeline.py", line 137, in run
    raise e
  File "pandasai/pipelines/pipeline.py", line 101, in run
    step_output = logic.execute(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandasai/pipelines/chat/code_cleaning.py", line 91, in execute
    code_to_run = self.get_code_to_run(input, code_context)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandasai/pipelines/chat/code_cleaning.py", line 137, in get_code_to_run
    code_to_run = self._clean_code(code, context)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandasai/pipelines/chat/code_cleaning.py", line 481, in _clean_code
    self._extract_fix_dataframe_redeclarations(node, clean_code_lines)
  File "pandasai/pipelines/chat/code_cleaning.py", line 384, in _extract_fix_dataframe_redeclarations
    env = get_environment(self._additional_dependencies)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandasai/helpers/optional.py", line 68, in get_environment
    **{builtin: __builtins__[builtin] for builtin in WHITELISTED_BUILTINS},
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandasai/helpers/optional.py", line 68, in <dictcomp>
    **{builtin: __builtins__[builtin] for builtin in WHITELISTED_BUILTINS},
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'help'

I'm utilizing the following code to package my program standalone:
`pyinstaller --collect-all pandasai --noconsole --copy-metadata pandasai --add-data "resources:resources" --add-data "finance-db.db:." --icon="./resources/icons/logo.png" --name money-management --pat /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.11 money-management.py
